# flutter - return/show plus sign of int

Tags: flutter, number-formatting

I'm trying to build some training app for functions for school. The problem is:
Everytime the randomly picked number is lower than 0, my function shows +-, because
I have a fixed format for my function.
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB4q2.png)

I tried to use the NumberFormat of the Intl-Package, but then I can't use the int-values correctly. Is there a way to show a plus sign for positive numbers, while they are still usable to work with them?

Code so far:

```
int randomNumberMinMax(int min, int max){
      int randomminmax = min + Random().nextInt(max - min);
      
      if(randomminmax==0){
        randomminmax = min + Random().nextInt(max - min);
      }
      //generate random number within minimum and maximum value
      return randomminmax;
    }
    
    int a = randomNumberMinMax(-5, 5);
    int b = randomNumberMinMax(-10, 10);
    int c = randomNumberMinMax(-10, 10);

    

    String task = "f(x) = $a(x+$b)²+ $c";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only show the plus when the number is positive like this for example

```
String task = "f(x) = $a(x${b >= 0 ? "+" : ""}$b)²${c >= 0 ? "+" : ""} $c";
```